# Matlab - Force to Retain Breakpoints

Tags: matlab, debugging, breakpoints

I wish to know, if there is a way to force `Matlab` **to retain all historically placed breakpoints** -red dots which enable code debugging- in the *Matlab Editor/Debugger* inside `functions`, `classes`, etc. from one *session* to another, for example, and without being deleted with `clear all` commands.

It would be easy for *debugging* huge pieces of software while changes are introduced, and because `Matlab` sometimes simply *shut down* because of internal errors.

[image: Matlab Editor Breakpoint]

Thanks fellows.

Answer (score 0):

`dbstop` is the cleaner solution. Just insert it in the place you want the debugging to stop and this will not be removed until you `edit` or `comment` the line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the breakpoints and reload them in next session. You can use [`dbstatus`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstatus.html) to get a structure that contains information about all breakpoints and save it into a file:

```
s = dbstatus('-completenames');
save FILENAME s
```

and later retrieve them using [`dbstop`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzm1h4-1)

```
load FILENAME
dbstop(s);
```

You can automate it by including it in [`startup.m`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) and [`finish.m`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/finish.html) files (create them on default user path if they don't exist).